# How can I set the focus of a ListBox in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, focus

I have this ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="lbColor">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Blue"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Red"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Orange"/>
</ListBox>
```

This code pre-selects the choice alright, but doesn't set the focus, how can I do that?

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lbColor.SelectedIndex = 1;
    lbColor.Focus = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx) method:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lbColor.SelectedIndex = 1;
    lbColor.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you have to inherit from UIElement-Class and set true to UIElement.IsFocusable. Now you should be able to set the focus to the listbox with lblcolor.Focus()! I hope that this will help.